# SQL Server Function Based Index Without Computed Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL Server query which is running slow due to the `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE LEFT(CustomerId,3) = 'ABC'
```

I need the `LEFT` function there as there are other customer IDs which begin with 'BCD', 'CDE' or 'DEF' and I only want those with ABC in my results. However, I need the query to be quick but the function is killing it, causing an index scan.

I know in Oracle there is a way to create a function based index so I would be able to do

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Customer_ID ON Customer (LEFT(CustomerId,3))
```

I would like to create similar functionality in SQL Server. I know I can do this using a computed column and creating an index on that column. However, I was wondering if there was a way to do this without a computed column?

Comment: `left(column, 3) = 'abc'` equals to `column like 'abc%'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create an index based on a function in SQL Server. You can however create an index on a computed column (with restrictions, such as the computation has to use only deterministic functions).

In your specific case, you don't have to use any functions, just to modify your query slightly.

Since `left(column, 3) = 'abc'` equals to `column like 'abc%'` you can safely use it. SQL Server is able to use indexes with the `LIKE` operator when the pattern contains a constant at the beginning (`abc` in this case).

Comment: Awesome thanks! That works without having to create the index. I didn't realise LIKE works differently as far as the optimizer is concerned

Comment: `LIKE` is a comparison operator, while `LEFT` is a function. The output of a function is hard to determine by the optimizer (sometimes even impossible).

Comment: Makes perfect sense when you say it like that. Many thanks for your help